# How to do I merge two objects with immutablejs?

Tags: immutable.js

I would like to supply one object and create a cloned object from it but overriding with new values without affecting the original object. I wanted to use immutablejs to ensure javascript objects are immutable.

Here is my example:

```
var map1 = Immutable.fromJS({
    selector:'DYNAMIC', 
    descendants:{
        icon:'x',           
        headingLink:'DYNAMIC',              
        text:'y',       
        readMoreLink:'z'    
    }
});

var map2 = map1.mergeDeep({
    selector:'NEW VALUE',
    descendants:{
        headingLink:'NEW VALUE'
    }
}).toObject();
```

I am expecting map2 to output:

```
{
        selector:'NEW VALUE',   
        descendants:{
            icon:'x',           
            headingLink:'NEW VALUE',                
            text:'y',       
            readMoreLink:'z'    
        }
    }
```

Instead I get this weird combination of ownerID, and __altered etc :

```
{
        selector:'NEW VALUE',   
        descendants:
            __altered: false,
            __hash:undefined,
            __ownerID:undefined,
            _root:pt,
            size:4
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions to help make this work would be much appreciated. If immutablejs cannot do this then perhaps an alternative library that will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toObject()` does a shallow conversion, going only one key down.

To convert the `descendants` Map to a plain JS object, you would have to do:

`map2.toObject().descendants.toObject()`

Not very elegant, and quite error prone. You could just do `map2.toJS()`, but it is rather inefficient if dealing with large sets of data.

Ideally, I wonder what your use case is? You can just write your entire App using Immutable.js without ever converting to plain JavaScript objects (except for use with 3rd party components and libraries). It’s a powerful library and any transformations you’re planning to do with your data can be done with Immutable.

If you are just looking for an immutable `deepMerge`, you could use `_.merge` from lodash which is available even as a separate module. Just note that the first argument in that function will be mutated (the merges are applied to it one by one), so pass in an empty object, `{}` and then your merge sources.

Comment: Thanks. It's more about readability. Yes I could just stick to immutablejs, but it's easier to see the changes I want to make to a data structure as a json map as I have provided above in my example. I will try the examples you have provided.

Comment: ok so lodash does merge the objects as I wanted to, but doesn't freeze the objects so they remain mutable which is not what I want.

Comment: There's a builtin [merge](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/merge) function (and mergeDeep) now...

Answer (score 1):

I have provided an alternative solution, using pure javascript. This is suitable for a small object. I'm not sure to what degree this will impact performance on large objects, but it seems really fast and almost the same if not a ms faster than lodash. The advantage over lodash is that it forces the object to be immutable.

```
var __ = {
  clone: function(obj){      
    var inst;
    if(Array.isArray(obj)){    

      inst = [];
      obj.forEach(function(item){
        inst.push(__.clone(item))
      });
    }else if(typeof obj === 'object'){            
      inst = {};
      for(key in obj){
        inst[key] = __.clone(obj[key]);
      }
      inst = Object.freeze(inst);
    }else{    
      inst = obj; // function, boolean, string, int, flt, date etc...
    }    
    // make this object immutable, so it cannot be changed.
    return inst;
  },
  recurseFreezeNew: function(objNew){
    var isArr = Array.isArray(objNew);
    if(!isArr && typeof objNew === 'object'){
      objNew = Object.freeze(objNew);
      for(key in objNew){
        objNew[key] = __.recurseFreezeNew(objNew[key]);
      }
    }else if(isArr){
            var self = this;
      objNew.forEach(function(item){
        item = __.recurseFreezeNew(item);
      });
    }
    return objNew;    
  },
  recurseMerge: function(objModel, objNew){
      var mergedResult;
      var key;

      var isModelArray = Array.isArray(objModel);
      var isNewArray = Array.isArray(objNew);

      var isModelObj = (!isModelArray && typeof objModel === 'object');
      var isNewObj = (!isNewArray && typeof objNew === 'object');

      var isBothObject = (isModelObj && isNewObj);    

      if(isBothObject){
        mergedResult = {};      
        for(key in objModel){
          if(!objNew[key]){
            mergedResult[key] = objModel[key]; //keep existing...
          }else{
            mergedResult[key] = __.recurseMerge(objModel[key], objNew[key]); // override new value
          }
        }

        for(key in objNew){
          if(!objModel[key]){
            mergedResult[key] = objNew[key]; // add new that don't exist...
          }
        }
        mergedResult = Object.freeze(mergedResult);
      }else{        
        objNew = __.recurseFreezeNew(objNew);        
        mergedResult = objNew;
      }            
      return mergedResult;
  }
};

var immutableMerge = function(){   
  var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var merged = __.clone(arr[0]);

  for(var i=1, intLen = arr.length; i < intLen; ++i){
    merged = __.recurseMerge(merged, arr[i]);
  }
  return merged;  
}


var merged = immutableMerge({
  'a':'default',
  'b':'default'
},{
  a:'NEW VALUE'
});
```

Example comparing immutablejs, lodash and this custom solution:
look at the console log to see the ms difference.
8, 3, 1 ms speed.

https://jsfiddle.net/ejyvpbwx/14/